# Text align center with justify

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to align center property with justify for text/content. Can Anyone of you help me. **With all browsers compatibility except IE versions**

see the screen for understanding. Want it justify only with text center...

Comment: This is not a question... It's more like "I don't have a clue, please provide the code...". Read on: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

At least provide a jsfiddle or anything you've done so far

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/serb5dsv/
Can you please justify now.. with center text

Answer (score 12):

you can try this:

```
.center-justified {
text-align: justify;
-moz-text-align-last: center;
text-align-last: center;
}
```

Comment: thanx for reply, but it's not browser compatible. Chrome didn't display correct result.

Comment: Good stuff :) I didn't know `text-align-last` property and is very interesting

Comment: @ShubhamTikare Chrome supports this since v35 but you need to enable an special configuration. Chrome sucks...http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last

Comment: This IS the right answer. BUT still requires the experimental web platforms flag in Chrome.
[CSS-Tricks: text-align-last](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align-last/)
And Chrome doesn't suck... depending on your needs it's the best browser out there...

Comment: With all browsers compatibility except IE versions --- Why I am write this

Comment: This is now (since about 8 years) compatible with Chrome (from version 47)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

html:

```
<div class="center-justified"></div>
```

css:

```
    .center-justified {
text-align: justify;
-moz-text-align-last: center;
text-align-last: center;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L4pzm/336/

Comment: No :( Want text align center with apply justify property which are already in css.

Comment: This only work in firefox.. I want all browsers compatible except IE versions

Answer (score 0):

```css
.justified-center {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="justified-center">...lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots
  and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots of text......lots and lots
  of text...</div>
```